# MS Excel LOOKUP from top to bottom column

Tags: excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function, worksheet

I have a problem finding a way for LOOKUP to search from top to bottom column. Here's the situation. I need to create a formula for Excel to search for hardware part inside a sentences.

Example :

> Sentence (A1)
>
> > Customer PC can't turn on. Check motherboard. Motherboard faulty. Replace motherboard. PSU don't have enough power. Replace PSU.

Here is lookup range column(HARDWARE)

- replace PSU
- replace motherboard

result range column(HARDWARE_PART)

- PSU
- motherboard

The formula I use is

`LOOKUP(9999;SEARCH(HARDWARE;A1);HARDWARE_PART)`

The result will be "motherboard". Because LOOKUP will search the column from bottom to top.

What I gonna do right now is for LOOKUP to search the column from top to bottom so that it can detect another replace part.

Answer (score 3):

Using named ranges is a good step; dynamic named ranges are even better. However, they present a problem by generating confusion trying to return the correct relative row number to an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) when they do not start in the first row.

My two named ranges (e.g. HARDWARE and HARDWARE_PART) used *Refers to:* formulas as,

```
=Sheet1!$AA$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$AA:$AA, MATCH("zzz",Sheet1!$AA:$AA))
=Sheet1!$AB$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$AB:$AB, MATCH("zzz",Sheet1!$AA:$AA))
```

This necessitated modifying the returned row by **1** since they started in the second row.

The standard formula in B1 is,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(HARDWARE_PART, AGGREGATE(15, 6, (ROW(HARDWARE)-1)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(HARDWARE, $A1)), COLUMN(A:A))), "")
```

Fill right for subsequent matches in descending priority.

[image: motherboard]

An [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) 'wrapper' can avoid showing `#NUM!` errors on non-matches by substituting the error return for a zero-legth string.

If you want to reverse the priority, swap out the **15** ([SMALL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29)) [AGGREGATE¹](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) option for **14** ([LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db)).

**Pre-xl2010 addendum**

For versions of Excel that cannot use the AGGREGATE function, this standard non-CSE formula duplicates the results. In B1 as,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(HARDWARE_PART, SMALL(INDEX(ROW(HARDWARE)-1+ISERROR(SEARCH(HARDWARE, $A1))*1E+99, , ), COLUMN(A:A))), "")
```

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: Hi Jeeped. Thanks for the feedback. I will change my named range to dynamic as you recommended. And thanks for the example. The problem is I'm still using Microsoft Office 2007. So I can't implement the AGGREGATE function

Comment: NyamO, I've added a pre-XL2010 version of the same formula.

Comment: OMG Jeeped. Thank you so much. You just save me. Truly appreciate it.