# Using VlookUp in VBA to search from bottom to top

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, excel-2013

I'm using a piece of VBA in a bigger macro to backup some of the comments made.
When returning these comments I'm using Vlookup in VBA. The problem is, Vlookup searches from top to bottom. I want to turn this around and make it search from bottom to top. How would i go and achieve this?
I've run out of Google-options.
Trying to learn from this, so please explain your solution, if possible.

To be exact, I'm using the code added below:

```
Dim Dept_Row As Long
Dim Dept_Clm As Long
Table1 = Sheets("16-Compliancy-Rebuild").Range("D85:D750")
Table2 = Sheets("OpmerkingBackup").Range("B2:F750")
Dept_Row = Sheets("16-Compliancy-Rebuild").Range("H85").Row
Dept_Clm = Sheets("16-Compliancy-Rebuild").Range("H85").Column
For Each cl In Table1
  Sheets("16-Compliancy-Rebuild").Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 5, False)
  Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
Next cl
```

Comment: http://www.atlaspm.com/toms-tutorials-for-excel/tom%E2%80%99s-tutorials-for-excel-using-vlookup-for-reverse-lookups/ Here are some ideas for reversing `VLookup`.

Comment: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/04/05/excel-lookup-function/ Bottom Up lookup

Comment: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108081/ms-excel-lookup-from-top-to-bottom-column). Jeeped's answer used named ranges but I don't think it is difficult to replace them with addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So instead of using a `VlookUp`, you can use [`.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff839746.aspx) instead. With this function you can clarify the Searchdirection, `xlPrevious` will search from bottom to top. The only difference is in the returnvalue, it gives back the cell with the match. The row of the Match (`rng.Row`) can now be used to get the dataset from the right column.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Sheets("16-Compliancy-Rebuild")
Set sht2 = Sheets("OpmerkingBackup")
Dim Dept_Row As Long
Dim Dept_Clm As Long
Dim rng As Range
Table1 = sht.Range("D85:D750")
Table2 = sht2.Range("B2:B750")
Dept_Row = sht.Range("H85").Row
Dept_Clm = sht.Range("H85").Column
For Each cl In Table1
    Set rng = Table2.Find(cl, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        sht.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 6).Value
    End If
  Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
Next cl
```

Other than that i also use variables for the Worksheets to make it easier to change and lookover.

Comment: Thanks for your clear solution. Only problem i seem to be having with your code is a double declaration of rng, which i can't seem to find. Anybody has a clue? Fixed the first one on the first row of VBA-code.

Comment: Use Ctr + F to search in the Code and you will find it.

Comment: Yeah, i feel quite stupid even asking. Other VBA code had a rng in it... Cheers for this UGP.